# How do I get an if statement to check if a user given number is a prime number?

Tags: java

I am writing a very basic program in Java to check if a number given by the user is a prime number.

I have tried to use an if statement to check if the number divided by itself is equal to 1 as well as if it is divided by 1 it equals itself, but when I run the program and enter a number there is no reaction at all from the if statement.

```
package prime.java;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Welcome to Prime!\nPlease enter a number:");
        
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int number = Scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(number);

        if (number%1 == number && number%number == 1) {
            System.out.println(number + " is a prime num");
        }
    }
}
```

Am I using the right operators?

Comment: first, figure out how you check what a prime number is, and how you verify that. create a method isPrimeNumber(int num), and call that.

Comment: Note this might get **very** expensive, supercomputers do this all day to calculate new prime numbers ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can help you:

```
static bool isPrime(int number)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
        {
            if((number% i) == 0)
            {
                // Not Prime
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Just Prime!
        return true;
    }
```

A prime number is not divisible by any numbers between 2 and (itself - 1).

This way, if you call 'isPrime()' inside the if, this just works.

Hope this can help you!

Comment: if n is not a prime, it would have at least one divisor k where k <= sqrt(n), so the loop does not have to run until the actual number, only until sqrt(n). if you did not find any divisors until sqrt(n), then n is a prime.

Comment: @TomElias Solid piece of advice, going to try this out myself.

Answer (score 2):

> , but when I run the program and enter a number there is no reaction
> at all from the if statement.

This is because the if condition is never fulfilled ( for example :  n%n will be 0 always)  .

Thus, you can keep a variable i that starts from 2 till number -1 and check if that number divided by i , the remainder should never be 0 .

```
public class PrimeNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 5;
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int i = 2; i < k; i++) {
            if (k % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            System.out.println("number " + k + " is prime");
        } else {
            System.out.println("number " + k + " is not prime");

        }
    }

}
```

and the output is :

```
number 5 is prime
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `isPrime` function to check if a given number is a prime or not, like below

```java
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    // Corner case
    if (n <= 1) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check from 2 to n-1
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

And replace your

`if (number%1 == number && number%number == 1)`

to

`if (isPrime(number)`

Comment: you only need to check until sqrt(n) ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is more efficient:

```
  boolean isPrime(int number) {
    int root = (int) Math.sqrt(number);
    for (int i = 2; i <= root; i++) {
      if ((number % i) == 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone is doing a project Euler problem.

You are close but I would suggest maybe looking into how you check if something actually is a prime number as the other comment suggested.

Research also some specifics of prime numbers, I will give one away which is : no prime number ends with 5. Implementing such rules can drastically reduce your programs run time.

And also you want to check out the correct usage of the modulo (%) operator.

```
 public static boolean isPrime(Long num){
    String number = String.valueOf(num);
    if(number.length() >= 2 ){
        //Lets see if a number ends with 5 if it does it is divisible by 2 and not prime
        if(number.endsWith("5")){
            return false;
        }
    }
    //No reason to check if a number is prime when it is 2.
    else if (num == 2){
        return true;
    }
    //Any number that can be devided by 2 with no remainder clearly isn't prime
    else if(num % 2 == 0){
        return false;
    }
    //All other numbers actually need to be checked.
    else{
        for (Long i = num -1; i > 2; i--) {
            if(num % i == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        }
        return true;
    }
```